# How to call app.get() after app.use() node js express? Pass request from app.use() to app.get()

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/', (req, res,next) => {
        res.send('Bid Request GET');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Bid  T');

});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('app listening on port 3000!'))
```

I am beginner in node js. When I run the code it only shows `app.use()` response not `app.get()` response.

I am confused. i tried next() method also, but not working. how to solve this?

Comment: You can try to set your response header in the first `app.use` and then use `res.write` to write the first chunk, call `next` to pass the request to `app.get` and use again `res.write`

Answer (score 2):

Main reason behind this is because you've already sent the response here:

```
app.use('/', (req, res,next) => {
    res.send('Bid Request GET');
});
```

You can only send one response per request.
Each `app.use` middleware is a function with access to request, response, next parameter. when next function is invoked, it executes the middleware succeeding the current middleware.

You can also pass data from one middleware to another by creating variable in request or response. For Ex.

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.body.token !== 'abc') return res.sendStatus(503)
    let someData = () => { .... SomeFunctionCode ... }
    req.myVarible = someData // or res.myVariable = someData or anything
    next()
})
```

But the recommended way of passing value is through `res.locals.myVariable`

Here is full example:

```
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.body.token !== 'abc') return res.sendStatus(503)
    let someData = () => { .... SomeFunctionCode ... }
    req.locals.myVarible = someData 
    next()
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(res.locals.myVariable)
})
```

Comment: good answer! I'd only like to add some further clarification. The difference between the two methods is that `app.get` is only for GET requests, while `app.use` applies to all request types. I'd also like to clarify that `app.get` accepts next parameters as well.

Comment: Wonderful explanation! I just wanted to mention the typo that the req.locals.myVarible = someData  should be changed with res.locals.myVarible = someData